# Stripe API. 2 (or more) Subscriptions, one PaymentIntent, one Charge, unnecessary canceled Payments in Dashboard

Tags: stripe-payments

**Use-case**: customer might have more than one subscription (different Stripe Prices) in a single order.

Right now we go the following way:

- for each subscription: create Stripe Subscription with "collection_method" => "send_invoice". This does not create PaymentIntent etc. automatically.
- for each subscription: get latest_invoice and finalize invoice
- create single Stripe PaymentIntent (with the price of all subscriptions) and confirm it
- for each subscription: get latest_invoice and update it as 'paid'
- for each subscription: 'collection_method' => 'charge_automatically'

**Problem**:
Technically this works good. However, this creates 2 (or more) unnecessary Payments with 'canceled' state in Stripe Dashboard (see attached image). Any way to avoid this?

**What we tried:**
Single subscription with 2 (or more) items is not a solution, because we match each subscription with an order for the further reference (we need a single order for each subscription for offsite payments).

**What we did not try**
Create a PaymentIntent per subscription. This is possible, but we try avoiding that because of the way payment processor module works for our CMS (it handles one payment intent only) and because too much charges at the same time increases the risk of some charges denied by Stripe/Bank.

**What could help us**
This can be avoided if we could create a subscription after the payment is captured, and mark their initial (1st) invoices as 'paid', allowing the following (2nd 3rd etc) invoices to be billed automatically, but at this moment this seems to be impossible.

Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

[image: Stripe Dashboard - 2 canceled payments]

Answer (score 0):

One possible way will be saving customer's payment method first, then create subscriptions with `collection_method: 'charge_automatically'` directly.

This will allow payment method to be collected once and customer will be charged to the saved payment methods in their Subscription. No invoice sending will be required in this case.

The steps will be:

1. Collect saved payment method: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-and-reuse?platform=web
2. In Subscription creation, set the payment method collected in Step 1 under `default_payment_method`: https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/create#create_subscription-default_payment_method

The subscriptions will create invoice and its Payment Intent automatically that manual Payment Intent is not required.

Comment: This is the default behavior and this approach creates X paymentintents (and X charges) for X subscriptions. What we are trying to do here is having X subscriptions and 1 charge only.